# Grails distinct projection get the result count of distinct items

Tags: grails, spring-security, criteria, hibernate-criteria, grails-2.0

I am using grails-2.5.6 version. I am using spring-security-core plugin. I have a criteria query on UserRole table. Where I want to find all distinct users by a role. It is working properly.

But the problem is the pagination effect. When I am counting on the list it is counting on UserRole list object. But I need the count on distinct projection items. Here is my attempt below:

```
def list(Integer max) {
    def userInstanceList = UserRole.createCriteria().list(params) {
        createAlias('user', 'au')
        createAlias('role', 'ar')
        projections {
            distinct("user")
        }
        if (params.roleId) {
            eq('ar.id', params.getLong("roleId"))
        }
    }
    def totalCount = userInstanceList.totalCount
    [userInstanceList: userInstanceList, totalCount: totalCount]
}
```

Here, totalCount is the number of UserRole list. But I want the distinct projection count.

Answer (score 0):

I would tackle this slightly differently, you want to analyse the users, not the userroles.

So I'd do something like:

```
List<User> usersWithRole = UserRole.createCriteria().list(params) {
      role {
        eq('id', params.getLong("roleId"))
      }
    }*.user

    int count = usersWithRole.size()
```

Unless of course there's hundreds or thousands of users, in which case I wouldn't want to load all of them each time and would revert to SQL.

Is this a custom version of spring security you're using?  I've never seen Roles with a 'long' based ID, usually, the key is a String representing the Authority name.

Comment: This is almost certainly not what the OP is going to want.  This doesn't tell you how many `UserRole` match the criteria.  `usersWithRole.size()` is going to tell you how many are returned, which may be a subset because `params` is passed to the `list` method.  The point of `.totalCount` is to tell you how many records match the criteria, which could be more than `usersWithRole.size()`.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown - But he wrote "Where I want to find all distinct users by a role."   - his question is a little ambiguous, maybe I got it wrong, but it seemed to me he wants the count of all users with a specific role.

Comment: "but it seemed to me he wants the count of all users with a specific role." - Agreed.  I am pointing out that `usersWithRole.size()` is not the way to do that.  That will evaluate to the number of rows in the result set, not necessarily the number of corresponding users in the database.

Comment: True, I should have omitted the params from the list method,  as I think it highly unlikely he really needs pagination to be performed against User Roles.   It'd be nice to hear back from the OP and receive some additional detail.

Comment: "as I think it highly unlikely he really needs pagination to be performed against User Roles" - that may be the case but if it is then he shouldn't be referencing the `.totalCount` property in his original example.  That results in another round trip to the database.  If all he really wants is the number of elements in the result set, `userInstanceList.size()` makes more sense than `userInstanceList.totalCount`.

Comment: We may never discover the true intent Jeff.   I'm curious though have you seen any variation of UserRoles with Long based Id's ?

Comment: " have you seen any variation of UserRoles with Long based Id's" - Yes.  All Gorm entities have Long based ids by default.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the DBAs see the use of `distinct` keyword as a code-smell.

In your case I would rather use the `User` as the main domain object to run the query against and a `group by` clause:

```
long id = params.getLong "roleId"

def list = User.createCriteria().list( params ) {
  projections{
    groupProperty 'userRole.role.id'
  }
  if( id )
    userRole{
      role{
        eq 'id', id
      }
    }
}
```